# how to open a file type pkz in ubuntu with a packet tracer version 6.0.3

Tags: software-installation

hello everyone I try open a file type pkz in ubuntu 16 and it say me that [image]

and I have this version: 
[image: version]

anyone know how to open this type of file in ubuntu with this version of packet tracer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is likely to be the Windows version for packet tracer so it might not be compatible.

> anyone know how to open this type of file in ubuntu with this version of packet tracer?

Install Virtualbox, Windows in it, Packet tracer in it. And then open the file in there.

Comment: I only can run this software with a VIrtual machine_